# Unusual limit problem

Tags: limits

I'm trying to solve this limit and I'm not really sure how to handle those kind of limits.

[Here is the limit:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfhFd.jpg)

> $$\lim_{x \to 0}\left[\frac{a}{x}\right]\frac{x}{b}$$

and here is my solution- 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U1z5.jpg).
$$t = \frac{1}{x}\rightarrow \lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{[at]}{bt}$$
I think that the limit is $0$ becuase $[at]< bt$ but im not really sure.
I also forget to mention that $a,b$ are constant real numbers.
Thanks!

Comment: What is $[.]$? Is it $\lfloor \ .\rfloor$?

Comment: $a\cdot t-1\leq \lfloor a\cdot t\rfloor \leq a\cdot t+1$ then just squeeze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, just because $f(t) < g(t)$ doesn't mean $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = 0$; for example, $t < 2t$ but $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{2t} = \frac{1}{2}$. Second, we have no reason to believe that $[at] < bt$ anyway - if $a = 10$ and $b = 1$, then $[at]$ will be larger than $bt$ whenever $t$ is at least $0.1$.

But $[at]$ is at least $at - 1$, and at most $at + 1$. So we can say $\frac{at - 1}{bt} \leq \frac{[at]}{bt} \leq \frac{at + 1}{bt}$, which gives us the opportunity to use the Squeeze Theorem. Computing the limits of those upper and lower bounds will give you your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\;\lfloor x\rfloor = x-\{x\}\;,\;\;\{x\}:=\;$ the fractional part of $\;x\;$ (at least for $\;x\ge0\;$ . For $\;x<0\;$ there seems to be some discussion about this...). Then

$$\left\lfloor\frac ax\right\rfloor\frac xb=\left(\frac ax-\left\{\frac ax\right\}\right)\frac xb=\frac ab-\left\{\frac ax\right\}\frac xb\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}\frac ab$$

since

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left\{\frac ax\right\}\frac xb=0\;\;\text{as this is a bounded function times one that converges to zero}$$